# Correct way to prevent instantiation in Java

Tags: java, oop, coding-style, semantics

If we want to prevent instantiation of object in Java we can use several approaches and most obvious of them:

1. abstract keyword
2. private/protected constructor

Let's say class doesn't contain abstract methods and we use **abstract** keyword to prevent creation of the object. Is this approach incorrect(I mean not syntax correctness, but semantic )? Or it's better to use private constructor in such cases?

Thanks

**UPD**
Class will be a base class for other, though it doesn't contain abstract methods. In my case it some "AbstractTestBase" which contains some common data and utility methods which can be used by some group of integration/unit tests.

Comment: final class with private constructor...

Comment: final class with private constructor throwing `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException` as hint

Comment: I would say use `abstract` only if you intend the class to be subclassed.  If it's a non-instantiable utility class or similar: a private constructor that throws an `AssertionError`

Comment: @miku, don't know why, but I use final class with private constructor in case if I don't need instantiation. Can you explain context?

Comment: @PradeepSimha, I would do the same - and might add a `throws java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`, so the intent is immediately obvious to the reader. But that's minutiae.

Comment: added description of the context to topic

Comment: @volodymyr If you want it to be subclassed you should just be using the `abstract` keyword: that's the intended use.  You shouldn't be using anything else since the constructor `will` still be called as part of the instantiation chain for child objects.

Comment: and also if you're worried about coding style you should tease out any "common" functions that don't belong within the responsibility of the object hierarchy itself.  The class should be inherently testable but testing specific code shouldn't be in the application classes unless it's used.

Comment: @MattWhipple yep, thanks for the hint, I've correct "private" to "private/protected". Though in my special case no one will be trying to create instance of abstract test, I'm interested in this question in general. But I'm not sure if there will be sense of such approach in some non-testing code.

Comment: @MattWhipple by inheritance I mean test classes, not the application classes itself.

Comment: @volodymyr Pick up a copy of "Effective Java" to answer these kinds of questions

Comment: @volodymyr - Theres no need for the constructors of this class to be restricted in any way. Simply use the `abstract` keyword and place all common functionality in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you want to use the class as subclass, the suggestion 'final class with private constructor' will not work obviously, so you'll have to go the 'abstract' way. From the definition of 'abstract class', this is legetimate, as the definition exactly states what you want:

> An abstract class is a class that is declared abstract—it may or may
> not include abstract methods. Abstract classes cannot be instantiated,
> but they can be subclassed.
>
> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html